# "keyset does not exist" error if user is not logged in

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I have an application (C# program that uses SharpSSH), and if I try to run it with the credentials of a user that is currently not logged in, I get a CryptographicException error saying "keyset does not exist".

If I run the application with the credentials of a user that is currently logged in, everything works fine.

Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

All other things being equal (like you have rights to access the credentials) I'm guessing the credentials you need are stored in the user's hive/profile.  I don't know which [certificate store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388136%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) SharpSSH will use (or even which SharpSSH you're using [there's one on codeplex and there's one on sourceforge]).

Assuming the credentials are tied to HKEYUser, to fix, you'd need to load the user's profile with [LoadUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762281%28VS.85%29.aspx).  That means you'll have to have a security token for the user (ie, you'll have to log them in, but it doesn't have to be interactively).  Or maybe you can change to a certificate store that's not tied to the user.